# Replace values between range to single value

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a column with numerical data in cells ranging from 1 to 500.
I want to replace numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 with string "1-9".
Meaning 
If cell has 1 then replace with "1-9".
If cell has 22 replace with "20-29"
And so on.

What is the formula to do this?

Please help.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Take a look at the `VLOOKUP` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crude way:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=1,"1-9",IF(LEN(A1)=2,LEFT(A1,1)&"0-"&LEFT(A1,1)&"9",IF(LEN(A1)=3,LEFT(A1,2)&"0-"&LEFT(A1,2)&"9")))
```

*Examples*

```
1     1-9
22    20-29
488   480-489
```

Assumes your values are listed in column A.